# How to properly setup TypoScript in a Functional Testcase for TYPO3 CMS 11?

Tags: testing, typo3, typoscript, functional-testing

I'm trying to load the TypoScript setup in a functional test into the TypoScriptFrontendController but failing on a lack of documentation / knowledge. How do you setup the TypoScript setup properly in a FunctionalTestCase so I can use it in the ContentObjectRenderer in TYPO3 CMS 11?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

To properly set up TypoScript in a Functional Testcase for TYPO3 CMS 11, you need to follow these steps:

1. Load TypoScript files: You can load TypoScript files in your test case by extending the Load TypoScript files: You can load TypoScript files in your test case by extending the setUpFrontendRootPage method and providing the TypoScript file paths. For example: method and providing the TypoScript file paths. For example:

   `protected function setUp(): void { parent::setUp(); $this->setUpBackendUserFromFixture(1); $this->setUpFrontendRootPage(1, ['EXT:your_extension/Configuration/TypoScript/YourTypoScriptFile.ts']); }`
2. Create a custom **FunctionalTestCase**: Extend the **FunctionalTestCase** and override the **setUp** method to include the loading of TypoScript files. Here's an example:

   use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Domain\Repository\Localization\LocalizationRepository;
   use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap;
   use TYPO3\TestingFramework\Core\Functional\FunctionalTestCase;

   class YourTestCase extends FunctionalTestCase
   {
   protected $testExtensionsToLoad = [
   'typo3conf/ext/your_extension/Tests/Functional/Fixtures/Extensions/test_extension',
   'typo3conf/ext/base_extension',
   ];

   ```
      protected function setUp(): void
      {
          parent::setUp();
          $this->setUpBackendUserFromFixture(1);
          $this->setUpFrontendRootPage(1, ['EXT:your_extension/Configuration/TypoScript/YourTypoScriptFile.ts']);
          $this->importCSVDataSet(ORIGINAL_ROOT . 'typo3/sysext/backend/Tests/Functional/Domain/Repository/Localization/Fixtures/DefaultPagesAndContent.csv');
          $this->subject = new LocalizationRepository();
      }
   ```

   }
3. Load additional files: If your system under test works with files, you can provide them by linking or copying them to the test instance. For example:

   /**

   - @var array
     */
     protected $pathsToLinkInTestInstance = [
     'typo3/sysext/impexp/Tests/Functional/Fixtures/Folders/fileadmin/user_upload/typo3_image2.jpg' => 'fileadmin/user_upload/typo3_image2.jpg',
     ];

By following these steps, you should be able to set up TypoScript in your Functional Testcase for TYPO3 CMS 11.

(I'm sorry stackoverflow didn't get the formatting right. I hope it helps anyway.)

Comment: One minor note - please don't use the ORIGINAL_ROOT + the "legacy path" variant. That won't work if `typo3/cms-composer-installers 4.0.0-RC1` is used with TYPO3 v11 OR TYPO3 v12 (enforcing typo3/cms-composer-installers ^5.0.0).

Better use a relative path from the testcase instead.